# shuffle random pair in array but excluding pair possibility

Tags: php, random, generator, shuffle

I wish to create a small script to generate a pair of users.

Users are in an array so I use shuffle to pair them randomly.

My problem is I want to avoid/exclude some pair of users in the final result.

So I have the first part to shuffle users :

```
<?php 

$user[] = "Miaa";
$user[] = "Xavier";
$user[] = "Antoine";
$user[] = "Marie-Ange";
$user[] = "Claire";
$user[] = "Orlando";
$user[] = "Camille";
$user[] = "Chloé";
$user[] = "Audrey";
$user[] = "*";

$users = count($user);
// Shuffle user
shuffle($user);// You get a shuffled array

// Pair the adjacent user
for ( $index = 0; $index < $users; $index +=2) {

    // Pair $user[$index ] with $user[$index +1]
    echo $user[$index ] . " <=> " . $user[$index+1] . "\n";
}

?>
```

Here it's a link with my code into a sandbox =>
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ef04e99946849606544493e64e317206209c10c

I tried to include an if statement but without success

```
$user[$index[0]] == "Miaa" && $user[$index[1]] == "Xavier"
```

Comment: Something like this ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2db1ff34477ca14ff03fcc3a3c7c491956c7a91a

Comment: Yep that's look like perfect for the if statement but If possible I wish to regenerate the shuffe each time a pair banned is resulted. I can simply refresh and wait for a good generation, but it's possible to do that directly in the code ?

Comment: Maybe good idea is to divide users in two arrays, shuffle both and create pairs from array1 <==> array2, if you can put users that should not be in one pair in same array. Sports event often are organize like that

Comment: You mean if the pair is found you have to restart the loop ?

Comment: Yes @executable restart the loop to finish without any pair banned

Comment: I hope this what you expected http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51b02fb9481a32d8f8418a9732249864d3fd8f6b

Comment: @executable that's perhaps the good way to do, but it's me be an error since when the banned pair result the script loop and return an error => http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1f163793a83b89f05c7b835d54a5be4eb20c35b

Answer (score 0):

u can get all the combinations and then get it via random key:)

```
<?php
$user[] = "Miaa";
$user[] = "Xavier";
$user[] = "Antoine";
$user[] = "Marie-Ange";
$user[] = "Claire";
$user[] = "Orlando";
$user[] = "Camille";
$user[] = "Chloé";
$user[] = "Audrey";
$user[] = "*";

$shufla = [];

foreach ($user as $us1) {
    foreach ($user as $us2) {
        if (
            ("Miaa" === $us1 and "Xavier" === $us2) ||
            ("Miaa" === $us2 and "Xavier" === $us1) ||
            ($us1 === $us2)
        ) continue;
        $shufla[] = $us1 . " <=> ". $us2;
    }
}

var_dump($shufla[mt_rand(0, count($shufla) - 1)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $firstGroup = [
        "Miaa",
        "Xavier"
    ];

    $secondGroup = [
        "Antoine",
        "Marie-Ang",
        "Claire",
        "Orlando",
        "Camille",
        "Chloé",
        "Audrey",
        "*",
    ];

    shuffle($secondGroup);

    // calculate how many users should be moved to first group
    $usersToMove = (count($secondGroup) + 2) / 2 - 2;

    //move random users to first group
    for ($i = 0; $i < $usersToMove; $i++) {
        $firstGroup[] = array_shift($secondGroup);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($firstGroup); $i++) {
        echo  $firstGroup[$i] . ' <=> ' . $secondGroup[$i];  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First I created the var `$err` to detect if the pair if found and to restart to loop. While restarting the loop the array `$res` who contains result empty. I parse in the end the result of the array.

```
<?php 

$user[] = "Miaa";
$user[] = "Xavier";
$user[] = "Antoine";
$user[] = "Marie-Ange";
$user[] = "Claire";
$user[] = "Orlando";
$user[] = "Camille";
$user[] = "Chloé";
$user[] = "Audrey";
$user[] = "*";

$users = count($user);
// Shuffle user
shuffle($user);// You get a shuffled array

// Pair the adjacent user
$err = 1;
$res = array();
while($err > 0){
    $err--;
    for ( $index = 0; $index < $users; $index +=2) {
        if(($user[$index ] == "Miaa" && $user[$index+1]  == "Xavier") || ($user[$index ] == "Xavier" && $user[$index+1]  == "Miaa")){
            $err = 1;
            $users = count($user);
            shuffle($user);
            unset($res);
            $res = array();
        }else{
            //echo $user[$index ] . " <=> " . $user[$index+1] . "\n";
            $res[] = [$user[$index ], $user[$index+1]];
        }
        // Pair $user[$index ] with $user[$index +1]

    }
}
$nb_res = count($res);
while($nb_res > 0){
    $nb_res--;
    $user1 = $res[$nb_res][0];
    $user2 = $res[$nb_res][1];
    echo $user1 . " <=> " . $user2 . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: That's look like really fine :)
A last point, a little bug it's present when the loop restart, it duplicate line.
To see this error I introduced more banned pair and I saw this bug =>
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/daca5ea1376bce9d7f0605ebdaf19bbe4bd8b47f

Comment: You expect a predefined number of results ?